# What are inheritAttrs: false and $attrs used for in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As the question suggests, I can't figure out their meaning and why I should use it. It's said that it can be used so that when we have many components and we want to pass data from parent to the child's child's child's component, we don't have to use props. Is this true?

It'd be nice If you could provide an easier example. Vue.js docs don't mention much on it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Disabling Attribute Inheritance"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance) section of the docs and the [api description](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) for the full details.

It's main usage is to define so-called "transparent" components that pass-through attributes. The example given in the doc is a component wrapping an `input` element:

```
// Component
Vue.component('base-input', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: ['label', 'value'],
  template: `
    <label>
      {{ label }}
      <input
        v-bind="$attrs"
        v-bind:value="value"
        v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      >
    </label>
  `
})

// Usage
<base-input
  v-model="username"
  required
  placeholder="Enter your username"
/>
```

The `required` and `placeholder` attributes are then set on the `input` instead of the wrapping `label`.

It doesn't really have anything to do with children of children of components but it can be used in such a hierarchy.

I hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: So basically, when you wrote <base-input v-model="username" require placeholder="enter your username"> it showed base input component. there we show another component which is <input> component and $attrs will be those that we didn't register as prop.  so in your example, it will be placeholder and required and they will be passed to <input> element as props. am I right?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili Sort of. They are available in the `$attrs` attribute, but they are *not* actual props. Props are available directly on the component. e.g. a prop named "myProp" will be available on the component via `this.myProp`. This is not the case for attributes. Props are meant for actual data while attributes are meant to be used directly in the html of the template.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili is there anything else?

Comment: So what happening when we don't bind ```v-bind="$attrs"```? I see it works as normal.

Comment: v-bind="$attrs" will tell vue that you wanna bind attrs supplied to the component to a given tag. Otherwise, it'll just disregard whatever isn't defined as a prop (because you'd effectively be trying to bind attrs to the top `<template>` tag which isn't actually rendered)
see: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs

Comment: can I explain it in this way that with `inheritAttrs: false`,  non-prop attribute bindings from the parent element will not fall through to reach any child element but if we use `v-bind="$attrs"` on any child element,then that child element will be able to get the non-prop attributes from the parent element ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed yes, if I understand your meaning correctly. Keep in mind this note from the API docs though: "Note: this option does not affect class and style bindings."

Comment: @bernie @IstiaqueAhmed AFAIU, also `style` and `class` attribute **will** fallthrough to the root element of the component irrespective you define `inheritAttrs: false` and even if you declare those (class & style) as `props`. Also `class` and `style` are not avaiable on `v-bind="$attrs` object. Thanks

Comment: @appu In Vue 3 the `style` and `class` is available on `$attrs`. They also apply only on the component with `v-bind="$attrs"`, not on the root element of component, when `inheritAttrs: false`.

Comment: what happen if I set `inheritAttrs: true`?

Answer (score 7):

For me talking about `$attrs` and `inheritAttrs` together, makes it harder to understand. So I will show a bit more observations.

I will call my base-inp from HTML like below

```
<base-inp label="Username:" v-model="username" 
required placeholder="Enter your username"></base-inp>
```

The HTML for base-inp is like below

```
<label>
    {{ label }}
    <input v-bind="$attrs" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
</label>
```

`v-bind="$attrs"` is used to bind attributes.

If you set `v-bind="$attrs"` and `inheritAttrs: true` (default) and render your base-inp component. It will render
[image]

So basically we are passing the attributes entered into base-inp component in the HTML template. And also into 'input' inside the base-inp. You can see 'placeholder' in both 'label' and 'input'.

If we delete `v-bind="$attrs"`, the placeholder won't be an attribute in inner 'input'
[image]

If you set `v-bind="$attrs"` and `inheritAttrs: false`, you will see attributes are not on the root element (label) but on inner input.
[image]

Comment: I was often using v-bind="$attr" but never knew about inheritAttrs. Thanks for the examples. It seems to me inheritAttrs=false is a cosmetical rather than anything practical. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: it's for keeping the root element clean not exactly cosmetic I would say

Comment: trying to understand why to use it. Can't clearly get it from the docs. Would you mind to clarify meaning of "clean" in this context? Also is it a Vue 3 specific feature? I can't see is it was in Vue2

Comment: clean in this context means root element does not have attributes. These all was Vue 2. I don't know about Vue 3