# Input field required Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js component input field and I use this component in different files . What I want is in some files I want the filed to be required.

Here is my Component : test-input

```
 <template> 
        <input type="text" value="Some value...">
    </template>
    export default {
    name:'test-input'
    }
```

Test1.vue :

```
<template> 
    <test-input required/>
</template>
```

Test2.vue :

```
<template> 
    <test-input/>
</template>
```

I tried to use required as you see up in test-input in test1.vue just i want this be required

Answer (score 0):

you should explicitly do a `<input v-bind="$props">` or a `<input v-bind="$attrs">`

[($attrs vs $props)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224091/what-are-inheritattrs-false-and-attrs-used-for-in-vue)

[medium article](https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/v-bind-props-1649cbd5f034)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have the value set by default? That way it is nevery empty unless you remove the text in the field. Didn't you mean "placeholder" instead of "value"?

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Some value..."/>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name:'test-input'
  }
</script>
```

That way it works for me:

```html
    <form action="#">
      <test-input required/>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: it tried it but it doesnt work , i found some ppl use :rules:required do you know any thing about it

Comment: No idea... But what about adding `props: { req: { Boolean, default: false }` to the component and then using it like `<TestInput :req="true" />`? I didn't try @CosimoChellini 's `<input v-bind="$props">` or `<input v-bind="$attrs">`.